# faster data fitting ( or learn) function in python scikit

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn

I am using scikit for my machine learning purposes . While I followed the steps exactly as mentioned in its official documentation but I encounter two problems. Here is the main part of the code :

1) trdata is training data created using sklearn.train_test_split.
2) ptest and ntest is test data of positives and negatives respectively

```
## Preprocessing

scaler = StandardScaler(); scaler.fit(trdata);

trdata = scaler.transform(trdata)
ptest = scaler.transform(ptest); ntest = scaler.transform(ntest)



## Building Classifier

# setting gamma and C for grid search optimization, RBF Kernel and SVM classifier

crange = 10.0**np.arange(-2,9); grange = 10.0**np.arange(-5,4)
pgrid = dict(gamma = grange, C = crange)
cv = StratifiedKFold(y = tg, n_folds = 3)

## Threshold Ranging

clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(),param_grid = pgrid, cv = cv, n_jobs = 8)


## Training Classifier: Semi Supervised Algorithm

clf.fit(trdata,tg,n_jobs=8)
```

Problem 1) When I use n_jobs = 8 in GridSearchCV, the code runs till GridSearchCV but hangs or say takes exceptionally long time without result in executing 'clf.fit' , even for a very small dataset. When I remove it then both execute but clf.fit takes very long time to converge for large datasets. My data size is 600 x 12 matrix for both positive and negatives. Can you tell me what exactly n_jobs will do and how it should be used? Also is there any faster fitting technique or modification in code that can be applied to make it faster ?

Problem 2) also StandardScaler should be used upon positive and negative data combined or separately for both ? I suppose it has to be used combined because then only we can use the scaler parameters upon the test sets.

Comment: for your problem2, use Scaler on P/N data altogether

Comment: ok thank you...
Can you just update me with one more information. The data with dimensions
m-samples x n-features,is normalised along the rows or along the columns ? I suppose it is done along the columns but then it is recommended to normalise the user input before classifying or predicting it with classifier. So how does the single input is normalised considering the fact that input will have 1 sample x n-features ? Obviously the normalisation can not be done along the features that is by row.

Comment: one more thing... The user input normalisation is done with same scale as the training data.

Comment: Ashutosh, normalize the data for each feature, so you may need to do it along the row. When your test data comes, use the same standard of normalization as your training data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVC seems to be very sensitive to the data that is not normalized, you may try to normalize the data by:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
trdata = preprocessing.scale(trdata)
```

Comment: Very important detail, I have seen few people mention this.